# Почему MDToolbar оказывается внизу экрана?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Пишу приложение для Android на Python и KivyMD, но столкнулся с такой проблемой: MDToolbar почему-то отображается внизу экрана. Код:

```
<MainScreen>:

    FitImage:
        source: 'skins/Paper.jpg'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:

    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_size: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
        
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Это кнопка'
```

Без Toolbar работает так, как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю,актуально ли ещё, но добавь под Toolbar:
pos_hint: {"top":1}